# What is typescript doing with the "=" in the function "export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch"

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Working on react app with react-redux + react-toolkit and I ran into some typescript syntax that puzzled me.

```
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```

What confused me is how '=' is being used in this line

```
export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch
```

I assumed it was just casting the type, like in `userInput as string`, but I changed the code around to `export const useAppDispatch: () => useDispatch as AppDispatch` intellisense was throwing a ton of errors.

What is this line of code doing?

Comment: It's the value of the  `const`. Without the type annotation it's just `export const useAppDispatch = useDispatch;` in JS

Comment: In the first version, the type of `useAppDispatch` is `() => AppDispatch`, that is a function that returns `AppDispatch`, your edited version is not valid code.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables + https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part that's probably confusing you is the [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables), which is the `: () => AppDispatch` part. The `:` indicates a type annotation, and the remainder is a [function type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions) that accepts no parameters and returns an `AppDispatch` instance.

Breaking it down:

- `export const useAppDispatch` - Export a const called `useAppDispatch`.
- `: () => AppDispatch` - Which has the type `() => AppDispatch` (a function accepting no parameters and returning an `AppDispatch` instance).
- `= useDispatch` - With `useDispatch` as the value of the const.

Once compiled to JavaScript, that will will be:

```
export const useAppDispatch = useDispatch;
```

Answer (score 0):

export const use App Dispatch: This declares a constant useAppDispatch. The export keyword makes it accessible from outside the module where it's defined.

(): () => AppDispatch: This is a function signature. It indicates that useAppDispatch is a function that takes no arguments (()) and returns a function that itself returns an AppDispatch type. espaceeely it's defining the type of the function.

= useDispatch: This part of the code is an assignment. It assigns the value of useDispatch to useAppDispatch. useDispatch seems to be a function or a reference to a function that returns AppDispatch.

Type Annotation: The : () => AppDispatch part before the assignment specifies the expected type of the function being assigned to useAppDispatch. It tells TypeScript that useAppDispatch should be a function that returns AppDispatch.

this code see like to be related to Redux and its useDispatch hook. It's creating a constant useAppDispatch that is meant to be a function with a specific signature (() => AppDispatch). The value assigned to useAppDispatch is inferred from useDispatch, ensuring that the assigned value adress to the defined function signature.

This kind of explicit type annotation and assignment in TypeScript helps  us
to maintain type safety and clarity when working with functions and their types.

Comment: there is no `(): () => AppDispatch` shown.